# To compute $\int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}dt$ cat I make the substitution $u=(1+ai)t$?, $a\in\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

To compute $$\int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}dt,$$ can I make the substitution $u=(1+ai)t$ ?

Here it works, but can I do that in general or it doesn't work always with complex number ?

Comment: But then remember that du = (1+ai)dt, so you have o divide by that somewhere

Comment: The integration is effectively over a ray in the complex plane, the substitution effectively rotates it back to the real axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly make the substitution, but since $u$ will be complex what you get will be a path integral over a path in the complex plane.

EDIT: If you want to equate that integral to the corresponding one over the real interval $[0,\infty)$, you'll then want to look at wedge-shaped contours 
such as this:

[image]

and see if you can control the integral over the circular arc.

Answer (score 1):

The prior solutions are altogether too complicated. There is a theorem for the [Integral of a Complex Gaussian](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Integral_Complex_Gaussian.html) that shows that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-pt^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}},\quad \forall p\in\mathbb{C};\, \Re\{p\}>0$$

Therefore we can say that

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(1+ia)^2t^2}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{(1+ia)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(1+ia)},\quad\forall\,|a|<1$$

by virtue of the symmetry of the integrand. I have verified this result numerically.

Comment: Robert's answer is exactly about proving this "thereom for the integral of a complex gaussian"

Comment: The proof of that theorem is a lot simpler than what Robert suggests. The difficulty with the transform $u=(1+ai)t$ is that the limits of integration are impacted. The proof in my link is much simpler. Moreover it underscores the point that in many instances complex numbers can be treated the same as 'real' numbers. I think you can ignore the fact that $p$ is complex and just carry out the integration as per usual. For example, my numerical solution makes no particular reference to the fact that $p$ is complex.

Comment: Using a path integral isn't complicated at all. And this is what the OP asked.

Comment: That the solution is analytically the same for $p$ real and complex is because... everything is complex analytic (for $\Re(p) > 0$)

Comment: So? Why go through all the machinations pretending it's something else?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If $\Re(p^2) > 0$ then $$\int_0^\infty e^{-p^2 x^2} dx = \int_0^{p\infty} e^{- z^2} \frac{dz}{p} = \frac{1}{p}\int_0^{\infty} e^{- z^2} dz+\frac{1}{p}\int_{\infty}^{p \infty} e^{- z^2} dz = \frac{1}{p}\int_0^{\infty} e^{- z^2} dz$$

Comment: I don't understand the equation you just posted; it's not what I wrote and the limits you wrote are not legitimate for complex $p$. Bottom line: I don't know what you're talking about. What's your point?

Comment: That's what I thought. What I wrote is perfectly legitimate **in complex analysis** because $f(z) = e^{-z^2}$ is complex analytic so it has a complex analytic primitive $F(z) = \int_0^z f(s) ds$.

Comment: My point is that complex analysis is not complicated : see I just proved the result in one line

Answer (score 0):

First I guess that $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|a|<1$ otherwise your integral diverge. For this scope we point out that the function

$$f(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}dt,$$ 
is smooth enough on $(-1,1)$ and its  derivative is given as follows

\begin{split}
f'(a) &= &-2i(1+ai) \int_0^\infty t^2 e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}dt,\\
&=&\frac{i}{1+ai} \int_0^\infty [-2t(1+ai)^2e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}] tdt,\\
&=&\frac{i}{1+ai} \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}[e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}] tdt,\qquad\text{(integration by part) }\\
&=&\frac{-i}{1+ai} \underbrace{\left[ te^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}\right]_0^\infty}_{=0} -\frac{i}{1+ai}\int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}dt,\\
&=&-\frac{i}{1+ai} f(a)
\end{split}
In fact $|te^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}| = te^{(a^2-1)t^2}\to 0$ since $|a|<1$. The case where $a\in \mathbb{C} $ it suffices to required $ Re [-(1+ai)^2] < 0$.

Whence, f satisfies ODE 
$$f'(a)=-\frac{i}{1+ai} f(a) \qquad \text{for }\qquad  Re [-(1+ai)^2] < 0$$

Which lead to 
$$f(a) = c (1+ai)$$
but $$ -c=f(0)= \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt  = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
that is

$$f(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ai)^2t^2}dt =-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(1+ai) $$
for $ Re [-(1+ai)^2] < 0 $ and this can be analytically extend for $a\in \mathbb{C}$ using complex analysis tools.